# Matplotlib event onclick store coordinates in variable?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, event-handling

I want to be able to use the coordinates of the point i click in my graph to use later on in my script.
I have been trying with global variables inside the onclick function and that does not work. Why?
Second question: how can i solve this?

Here´s my simplified code where i attempt to store the x coordinates in the variable x. After the script is complete the x variable has the value -999, i.e. the initiation value. I want it to get the x coordinate of my mouse click on the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

x = -999


def onclick(event):
    print (event.xdata, event.ydata)
    global x
    x = event.xdata
    print(x)
    plt.close()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. If you print the `x` variable at the very end, after `plt.show`, you will get the right value for `x`.

See code below and example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

x = -999


def onclick(event):
    print (event.xdata, event.ydata)
    global x
    x = event.xdata
    plt.close()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
print('x_pos '+str(x))
```

And the output gives:

```
1.1866935483870962 0.6654995725561207
x_pos 1.1866935483870962
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. If i use exactly your code i get however:   <br/>`x_pos -999 
4.87923387096774 0.5276053672087042` That is the x_pos variable is read before the function is called. Is there a setting we have different?